# Switch firewall profile on shutdown and run Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall

In Windows 7 Firewall, I'd like to have two profiles/policies:
- one rather restricted where every internet traffic has to go through a VPN
- another one that allows (only) Windows Update to use my ISP connection to update Windows 
In addition, I'd like to automatically switch these two on shutdown, and let Windows check for and install updates every time I shut down my computer.

Any ideas how to do that? So far, I was able to setup the first policy mentioned above. How do I need to setup the other one? How do I do the automatic switching (.bat-files with task scheduling?)

Comment: Hmm. Windows cannot check for updates when it is shutdown :)

Comment: Yah, that's why I wrote "on shutdown" :-) Guess I'd have to write a custom script that switches firewall policies first, then starts Windows Update, then shuts down the computer?!

Comment: Something like that :)